# Customise authenticate_user devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Currently I have an Ajax call via a button click that updates a shopping cart, but the controller that it posts to has the `authenticate_user!` before_filter applied, which is what I want, as a user must be logged in.

Because it's an ajax call I normally just get a `401` error and no redirect, so to solve this I have:

```
$(document).on "ajaxError", (event, request, settings) ->
  if request.status == 401
    window.location.href = '/users/login'
```

However this is causing me issues with getting the flash[:notice] to appear as it's lost by the time i get to the login page.

From doing some reading on various posts on here I understand that I can use `flash.keep` which would persist my message, but I think to do that I am going to have to change my approach on handling the redirect. If I can do this in the controller I could also use `if request.xhr?`, couldn't I?

My question is how would I add this functionality whilst keeping all existing functionality of the `authenticated_user!` helper method. From looking at the devise docs the helper is dynamically built, isn't it?

I know I could put a helper into my application controller:

```
def authenticate_user!
  super
end
```

So expanding on that I have tried

```
def authenticate_user!
  if request.xhr?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to new_user_session_path }
    end
  else
    super
  end
```

But when clicking the update button, which is this

```
$(window).load ->
  $('a[data-target]').click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $this = $(this)
  if $this.data('target') == 'Add to'
   url = $this.data('addurl')
   new_target = "Remove from"
  else
    url = $this.data('removeurl')
    new_target = "Add to"
  $.ajax url: url, type: 'put', success: (data) ->
  $('.badge-number').html(data)
  $this.find('span').html(new_target)
  $this.data('target', new_target)
```

I get this error in the console

```
Routing Error

No route matches [PUT] "/users/login"
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: what is your update method in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds quite high-friction from the user point of view. If I click "add to cart", I expect the thing to be added to the cart. I certainly don't expect to be redirected to a login/signup page. At this point, I would just navigate away.

A better approach is, if user is not logged in, create a **guest user** and write its id to the cookies. Guest user has cart, can add stuff, etc.

Then, at checkout page, you offer the choice "login" / "sign up". In either case, you get a real user. At which point you migrate guest cart and delete the guest user.

#### Example:

```
def current_or_guest_user
  return guest_user unless current_user

  # current user exists. And we found a guest user
  if session[:guest_user_id]
    transfer_guest_user_stuff # cart, posts and what-have-you
    guest_user.destroy
    session[:guest_user_id] = nil
  end
  current_user
end

def guest_user
  unless @cached_guest_user
    @cached_guest_user = User.find_or_create_by(id: session[:guest_user_id], is_guest: true)
    session[:guest_user_id] = @cached_guest_user.id
  end

  @cached_guest_user
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a very valid point. I use the current_user helper method when displaying the cart so I guess I would have to actually create the guest user, maybe in a before action? Or can I achieve the same using the cookies as you have stated?

Comment: @Richlewis: Added some code to the answer. This is almost exactly what we use.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, can't wait to try it out

Comment: `guest_user` is good solution, but only in case when we should record `shoping card` on some long time. We should use small_time_living for `shoping card` to avoid erroneous users orders. (Some time ago user put in cart something, then close windows, find something else and put it one to cart too. User press `pay shoping cart` and will see someones what don't want to buy... IMHO, `shoping cart` don't required strong security code if after this user will pay money for own orders...

Comment: @СергійНазаревич: it's cart, not card :)

Comment: @ Sergio Tulentsev, yeah! Thanx!

Comment: @СергійНазаревич also don't abuse backticks. They're for highlighting code, not random words.

Comment: Currently I store my object ( purchase for cart) in Redis, and update via Ajax, would I be better having a cart model and storing there instead of in Redis? Oh and merry Christmas all :-)

Comment: @Richlewis: user cart is something that I'd like to be persisted. In a database, not in an in-memory store. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so looking at this today and I am wondering how `session[:guest_user_id]` is being set ? returns nil when I am inspecting further, also cant create user as validation fails (need email and password), would like to skip using `validate: false` but cant seem to with `find_or_create_by` any ideas or am I not understanding something :-)

Comment: @Richlewis: you can make the validations conditional (skipped for guest users). `validate_presence_of :email, unless: :guest?`, or something

Comment: thanks, daft question but does this guest_user already exist in the database, we are not creating a new one each time are we ? I've been looking at this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user aswell

Comment: We are not creating a new one each time, hence the "__find__ _or_create_by"

Comment: ok, so how does it find with `id: session[:guest_user_id], ` when it doesn't exist (if this is my first time accessing the site), because initially that is always nil

Comment: think I may have to book a session with you on codementor

Comment: @Richlewis: if it doesn't exist, then it is created. This is how "find_or_create_by" works. "find by these params" or "create with these params". Are you not familiar with the method?

Comment: @Richlewis: yeah, codementor is great for clearing this kind of questions, because of much higher "bandwidth" of communication

Comment: yes familiar with the method, and yes difficult to get points across via comments. My understanding is falling down at the point where, if these params do not exist set the the id as `session[:guest_user_id]`, but where is that coming from, as first time around it wont exist... anyway will look at sorting a session out

Answer (score 0):

As the first piece of advice, You could use [Trubolinks gem](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) which provide all AJAX functionality "in-box" and is default in Rails 4+.

As the second piece of advice, You could generate Users Controler ( `rails generate devise:controllers Users`) and\or Devise modules such as sessions. passwords and other controlers with [Customize Devise Tools](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers).

Additionally, You could customize `before_filter` in certain Controller's code, for example:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :store_location
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:new, :delete]
```

In this sample, `:authenticate_user` should be only for `:new` and `:delete` methods. Other methods not require users authentication ...

I hope it help You!

Comment: If he disables `authenticate_user` for cart update, to which user's cart will the item go?

Comment: `Where live` `shoping cart`? Its live in sessions as instance of `shoping cart` object. While user don't close window, it would be acceptable to use...

Comment: Not necessarily. It could go to database too.

Comment: yes! I wrote in other comment -- if we have to write it into database,  `guast_user` solution is the Best! :)